# Create partition on SD card in ubuntu terminal

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card

I inserted a new SD card on ubuntu. When i gave `lsblk` command to get to know the path for mounting, I got this

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk1      179:0    0  59.5G  0 disk
```

this disk is does not have any partition, how to create a partition like `mmcblk1p1` and that partition will have the entire space of the SD card

thanks

Comment: This is impossible since a partition must not use the space needed by the partition table, thus a partition can never have the entire space.

Comment: Note that a single partition can be made under certain conditions (USB-stick?), but that might end up be a problematic device for some operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insert the FULL QUESTION in the QUESTION TEXT.

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk1
[sudo] password for *$USER*:           

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): m
```

The `m` <kbd>Enter</kbd> command lists the available commands.
l - list current partitions
d - delete partition, if you have one or more
G - create a GPT partition table
o - create a DOS partition table
n - add a NEW partition.

If there is no partition table nor partitions:
Do `G`, and then `n` for a FAT or exFAT partition, then
`w` to write that to the "disk" (SD-card).
`q` to quit fdisk

---

`$ sudo apt install gparted` # if not already installed.
`$ gparted &` # launch it
... then use the GUI.

First select `/dev/mmcblk1` in the upper right corner.

Select a sequence of operations to do,
(i.e. create a partition table, a partition, format it, ...)
then click the green `✅` to actually do those operations.

Comment: The question asks for a *terminal* method, gparted is a GUI

Comment: That detail is not in the QUESTION TEXT.  Bummer.

Comment: I tried gparted GUI, the options are not enabled, then using fdisk method works, thanks

Comment: "not enabled" - hmm... did you select the "disk" to work on first? Or possibly; it doesn't allow a partition before there is a partition table.